# What is override public object ActivateInstance() in XamlTypeInfo.g.cs?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

What is **override public object ActivateInstance()** in **XamlTypeInfo.g.cs**? When it is executed and what is the role of this method.

Since it's created during compilation. What are the objects will come under **ActivateInstance** and what's its main responsibility and how it access other functionality.

I came across this while debugging my project and searched for it in google. I didn't find any answers. So am raising this question here.

What does **Activator** returns??

Can anyone please share me the details and help me?

```
override public object ActivateInstance()
{
    return Activator(); 
}
```

Comment: What's the question that you're facing? Errors? Exceptions? You'd better provide a [mcve] to show what you have done.